# Value of declared but uninitialized int variable in c

Tags: c, int

I am new at C and using DevC++ as my IDE.

I learned that if variables are declared but not assigned any value they are initialized with a random value (except static and global variables which are initialized with 0).

But when I tried this:

```
int i, j, k;             
printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);
```

it printed:

always 0 for i;
any large random integer (always different) for j;
a large random integer (always same) for k.

here is the output on running the above code 5 times: 0 13308816 32764
                                                      0 12391312 32764
                                                      0 11408272 32764
                                                      0 11015056 32764
                                                      0 7541648 32764

But I think these all should print random values (garbage values), different every time (same as for j).

Comment: `I learned that if variables are declared but not assigned any value they are initialized with a random valu` wrong!! Infact they are not initialized to any value at all. Whatever values that particular memory was having previously will be left as it is.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, no one should be using DevC++ in 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C has always been very specific about the initial values of objects. If global or static, they will be zeroed. If auto, the value is **indeterminate**.

Comment: To add: "indeterminate value: either an unspecified value or a trap representation"  Then to add details on _unspecified_, _trap_.